# "org.datanucleus" is already registered under Spring Source Toosuite

Tags: gwt, spring-roo, datanucleus

Exception in thread "main" Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/zakaria/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/1.1.6/datanucleus-core-1.1.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/zakaria/springsource/sts-2.3.3.M2/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.5_1.3.5.v201007021040/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/lib/user/orm/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar."
    org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/zakaria/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/1.1.6/datanucleus-core-1.1.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/zakaria/springsource/sts-2.3.3.M2/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.5_1.3.5.v201007021040/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/lib/user/orm/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar."
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:434)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:340)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:222)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:153)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.registerExtensionPoints(PluginManager.java:82)
        at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.(OMFContext.java:160)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)

Can you help me please? I tried to re-enter the following command in the built-in Roo Shell but no way:

```
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
```

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you have two "datanucleus-core" jars in the CLASSPATH, so check your CLASSPATH

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Where is set the classpath in the Springsource Too Suite? Or must I do it manually?
Regards.

Comment: Are talking about the ".classpath" file?